# Log stdout to journal from SystemD

Tags: linux, systemd, journalctl

I have a service unit with the following lines:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
```

When my service logs to stderr, I can see the logs with `journalctl -f -t my-service`.

But when I change the service to write the log to stdout, journalctl shows nothing.

What can be happening? Is there something that I should be configuring in adition to this?